# stat returns ENOENT

Tags: c, linux, stat

I am running the following program, which checks if a file exists or not using `stat()`. But, when I am passing a path say, `$HOME/file.sh`, it fails with `ENOENT` error. But when I pass the expanded path i.e. `/root/file.sh`, `stat()` returns success i.e. exit code 0.

```
int main ()
{
    struct stat statbuf;
    char path [1024];
    strcpy(path,"$HOME/file.sh");

    int rc = stat(path,&statbuf);

    if (rc == -1 )
    {
        printf ("File not found !!\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Found it !!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: $HOME has meaning to shell scripts, but not C programs. You are asking stat to look for a file named file.sh in a directory named $HOME which is below your current working directory.

Answer (score 4):

`strcpy()` will not expand the environment variable `$HOME` to its value, but will copy the extract string literal as specified. You can obtain the value of `$HOME` using [`getenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv).

Change your failure message to:

```
printf("File not found: %s\n", path);
```

for confirmation.

Comment: Yes, but that is not my concern. I could have directly passed $HOME/file.sh to stat. but my question is do I need to pass an absolute path to stat ?

Comment: @trax_code, no you do not. If the path is not absolute then the path is treated as a relative path and it will be relative to the current directory of the process.

Comment: ok. one question. By current directory, you mean the directory from where i am running the executable ?

Comment: @trax_code, yes. You can obtain the current directory of your process using [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) if you would like to display for diagnostic purpose.

Comment: `stat()` doesn't expand the env/ var/ `$HOME` neither. Expansion is done by the shell, and `stat()` won't use the shell. @trax_code